# Need guidance to use .map,.group,.pluck, etc. to make multi series line chart in ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, chartkick

I'm trying to display a multi series line chart using `chartkick` in a Ruby on Rails app.

The chart should display `paper_types` and the `weight`for each type during some time period.

**SCREENSHOT ADDED**

[image]

This is my **latest try**:

```
<%= line_chart [                            
  {name: @pappi.map{|p| [p.paper_type]}, data: @pappi.map{|t| [t.date, t.paper_weight] }, 'interpolateNulls':true}
 ] %>
```

Where `@pappi = Paper.all`

The code above outputs as the picture below, where every `paper_type` rounds up on one single line, instead of showing separate lines for each `paper_type`.
[image]

**What I'm looking for** is a chart similar to the screenshot below, were each paper_type has it's own line.

[image]

Can someone please help me with this so I can get the outcome I want?

Comment: Can you remove most of this answer's content and define: *what you want* (maybe a screenshot as example?), *the context you have* (records and their attributes relevant to the problem) and *what you did* (last 2 tries that were the closest to the answer)

Comment: yes I will, give me few minutes :)

Comment: As I closed your "duplicated" question today and you don't have a lot of reputation to put on a bounty, I will do my best to help you fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you @MrYoshiji thats very kind of you, I've edited the question and added a sample image from the chartkick documentation

Comment: following the `line_chart` example, you need to provide an array of hashes, each hash define the `name` key/value pair (value will be displayed in the legend), and the `data` key/value pair (value contains a hash of  key/value pairs, where the key is a date, value is a number).

Comment: thank you @MrYoshiji could you perhaps give me an example, I'm feeling kind of lost here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not test this, only read the doc and concluded the following:

`line_chart` expects you to give argument structured like this: (from the Javascript documentation)

```
line_chart [
  { name: 'Line1', data: { '2017-01-01' => 2, '2017-01-08' => 3 } },
  { name: 'Line2', data: { '2017-01-01' => 1, '2017-01-08' => 7 } },
]
# try it in your view to make sure it works as described below
```

This will create a chart with 2 lines (Line1 and Line2), horizontal axis will contain 2 values 2017-01-01 and 2017-01-08 and the vertical axis will be a scale, probably from 1 to 7 (min from data to max from data).

---

Following this data structure **in your context**:

Specs (correct me if I am wrong):

- one line for each different `paper_type`
- `weight` value for a given `paper_type` and a given date

Object mapping to match the desired data structure:

```
# controller
all_paper_type_values = Paper.all.pluck(:paper_type).uniq
@data_for_chart = all_paper_type_values.map do |paper_type|
  { name: paper_type, data: Paper.where(paper_type: paper_type).group_by_month(:created_at).sum(:weight) }
end

# view
<%= line_chart(@data_for_chart) %>
```

This is no scoped to any user / dates (period). You will have to include this in the code above.

Try this and let me know if it fails.

Comment: thank you @MrYoshiji  this works, but I'm concerned how I can show different paper_types and paper_weights by using this method.  One user have maybe 4 paper_types (Newspaper, magazines, officepaper and other paper) and then another user have perhaps only two paper_types to show( newspaper and officepaper). For that user I would only have the graph to show those two types but not all four.

Comment: didn't see your edit before commenting, I'll check it out

Comment: I get `undefined local variable or method `data_for_chart' for #<#<Class:0x007fc7694aea60>:0x007fc768448c70>`

Comment: Yeah, this is working 95%, I now have separate lines for each paper_type, but it is not showing the weight. I added a screenshot to the question of how it looks now

Comment: So, as seen in the screenshot I added, the legend is showing the number of entries for each paper_type. I can understand that is because the code is not showing any paper_weight, my concern now is how to add the paper_weight to the code so it will be shown in the legend?

Comment: What is the output and/or the SQL generated for `Paper.grouped_by_month(:created_at)`? The `.count` instruction is counting records instead of summing all of those records' `weight` value

Comment: this is what I get, I'm not understanding it fully `irb(main):005:0> Paper.group_by_month(:created_at)
  Paper Load (5.1ms)  SELECT "papers".* FROM "papers" WHERE (created_at IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('month', (created_at::timestamptz - INTERVAL '0 hour') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC') + INTERVAL '0 hour') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "papers.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "papers".* FROM "papers" WHERE (created_at IS NOT NUL...`

Comment: Can you try `Paper.grouped_by_month(:created_at).sum(:weight)`? And eventually `Paper.grouped_by_month(:created_at).select('SUM(weight) as total_weight')`

Comment: I get `irb(main):007:0> Paper.group_by_month(:created_at).sum(:paper_weight)
   (9.9ms)  SELECT SUM("papers"."paper_weight") AS sum_paper_weight, (DATE_TRUNC('month', (created_at::timestamptz - INTERVAL '0 hour') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC') + INTERVAL '0 hour') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC' AS month FROM "papers" WHERE (created_at IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('month', (created_at::timestamptz - INTERVAL '0 hour') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC') + INTERVAL '0 hour') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC'
=> {Sat, 01 Apr 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00=>#<BigDecimal:7f8887a17680,'0.621E3',9(18)>, Mon, 01 May 2017` 
to long to sh

Comment: That is perfect. Use this `.sum(:weight)` instead of the `.count` in your code (see updated answer)

Comment: Fantastic!!!! @MrYoshiji, You just made my day!!!! Thank you so much for all your help

Comment: I am happy to help. I assume you will be able to filter Paper based on the desired user and/or a period of time.

Comment: Yes exactly, this seems to be working as it should now

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you put any of these options in the rails console? Do you get multiple series of data?

Have you tried?

`<%= line_chart [ name: paper.paper_type, data: current_user.papers.group(:paper_type).group_by_week(:created_at).count ] %>`

Comment: Thank you @Stuart, Yes I've tried this, it gives just an empty graph

Comment: I'm not sure how I should put these options in the console, being rather new to this and all :)

Comment: At a terminal, type in `rails c`. Have you done this? If not, you can read about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html.

Once there, you can do `current_user.papers.group(:paper_type).group_by_week(:created_at).count` to see what the results are. I would spend my time doing this. When you get data that looks correct, try the chart.